# Variable access/modification inside class not working

Tags: c++, class, console, codeblocks, iostream

I'm trying to make something like the menu showing app (to be specific it shows me a menu, I choose an option (in that case number 1, this works) and then I want it to show me something like that:

```
[Name]
-----------------
[Decription]

Press any key....
```

and after I press any button I want it to show the parent menu
In this case it should be like that Glowne (Main Menu) executes test item's show function and then it should return back to Glowne showing this in the meantime:

```
Test String
---------------
Test Description

Press any key....
```

The problem is that I'm getting

```
<empty line>
4763656---------------------------------------
<empty line>
<empty line>
```

and the app crashes.

Source code is as follows:
hpstream.h

```
#ifndef HPSTREAM_H
#define HPSTREAM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Item;

class Menu
{
public:
    list<Item> Children;
    list<Item>::iterator it;
    Menu* Parent;
    void ShowMain();
    void SelectOption(int howMany);
    void Show();
    void AddChildren(Item& objekt);

private:
    bool FirstShow;
};

class hpstream
{
public:
    static void GetHelp();
};

class Item
{
public:
    string Name;
    string Description;
    bool isMenu;
    Menu* ChildrenMenu;
    Menu* Parent;
    void Set(string _text, string _Desciption, Menu* _Parent);
    void Show();
};

#endif // HPSTREAM_H
```

and hpstream.cpp:

```
#include "hpstream.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

Menu MainMenu;

void hpstream::GetHelp()
{
    Item test;
    test.Set("Test String", "Test Description", &MainMenu);
    MainMenu.AddChildren(test);
    MainMenu.Show();
}

void Menu::ShowMain()
{
    MainMenu.Show();
}

void Menu::SelectOption(int howMany)
{
    bool done = false;
    int Option = -1;
    while(!done)
    {
        char character = getch();
        //converts pressed key to number, returns to selected list position (with iterator) and shows it
        if (character >= 49 && character < 49 + howMany) //1-8
        {
            Option = character - 48;
            for (int i = 0; i < (howMany - Option); it--);
            it -> Show();
            done = true;
        }
    }
}

void Menu::Show()
{
    system("cls");
    it = Children.begin();
    for (; it != Children.end();)
    {
        int shown = 0;
        cout << "Select number (for test 1)" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; (i < 9) && (it != Children.end()); it++)
        {
            cout << i << ". " << it->Name << endl;
            shown = i; // so it will contain as many positions as possible but less or equal to 8
        }
        SelectOption(shown); //here it's like SelectOption(1);
    }
}

void Menu::AddChildren(Item& objekt)
{
    Children.push_back(objekt);
}

void Item::Set(string _text, string _Desciption, Menu* _Parent)
{
    this -> Name = _text;
    this -> Description = _Desciption;
    this -> Parent = _Parent;
}

void Item::Show()
{
    if (!isMenu)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << this -> Name << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        cout << this -> Description << endl << endl;
        cout << "Press any key...";
        getch();
        this -> Parent -> Show();
    }
}
```

and main.cpp (for executing):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hpstream.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    hpstream::GetHelp();
    return 0;
}
```

I know I shouldn't place multiple classes in the same file but I really had to.
The problem exists in the Item::Show() function (it is responsible for generating that "interface" shown at the beginning)

The Function that is executed as the "starting point" is hpstream::GetHelp(const char* _topic)

If there are any problems with variable names they are caused by missing them while translating source code, the problem is not connected with that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Actually I have placed only the source code that can contain the problem, it can be in one of those two classes and I don't know in which one.

Comment: though I still cut everything I could apart from the straight path leading to a bug.

Comment: @Grzegorz Keep cutting. You've got two classes with a bunch of functions, keep trimming things down until the error goes away. Then provide the minimal code that exhibited the error. And make sure your minimal example is _complete_, so that a reader can compile your code and reproduce your problem.

Comment: now it's cut as much as possible.